# Can I call a REST webservice an 'XML webservice'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

Since REST services do not require XML, but we can use it with XML so can I call it a XML web service?

I'm doing my home work with the requirement that:

1. Using ASP.NET MVC
2. Provide an XML Web service

I was thinking about SOAP, but REST is more simple for me and I found alot of tut for REST with ASP.NET MVC rather than SOAP (They now all telling me about WCF...)

If REST is not an XML web service, please show some basic document about SOAP (or any thing else that call XML web service) with ASP.NET MVC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [WCF Web Api](http://wcf.codeplex.com/). REST does not imply any particular format. A good REST service will allow you to set the Accept Header: json, xml, so on. E.g.: "accept" : "application/json"
Here is a good [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/returning_json_from_wcfwebapi) on how to achieve this with WCF Web Api.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Web Service into your MVC application. You must take care about exclude "*.asmx" from your routes.

I.E:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```